# how to invoke the job configured in 1 jenkins( remote jenkins) from another jenkins (local)

Tags: jenkins

I have 2 Jenkins ,1 is local Jenkins(setup on my laptop) and another Jenkins is setup in remote VM

I have configured 1 job on remote Jenkins .Now I want to create a job on my local Jenkins which should invoke the job configured in remote Jenkins.

I have no idea how to achieve that.Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Check https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API

> **Jobs without parameters**
>
> You merely need to perform an HTTP POST on
>   JENKINS_URL/job/JOBNAME/build?token=TOKEN where TOKEN is set up in the
>   job configuration.